# When select box option is selected, hide and uncheck corresponding checkbox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, select, checkbox

When an option is selected the corresponding checkbox `<div>` is automatically hidden using jQuery. For example, user selects Item 1 from the select box, and `<div class="item1">` is immediately hidden.

**Caveat:** Both will be visible, so the user changing the select option must be accounted for (eg. user selects an option who's corresponding checkbox has already been checked). The checked state must be removed and the corresponding `<div>` should hide.

Needs to be compatible with FF, Safari, Opera, IE7 + 8 (6 if possible, not required)

**Update**: The corresponding `<div>` of the default selected option should be hidden on page load.

**Update 2**: This is now resolved. Thanks a ton to both Joel and ckramer. Both proposed solutions work perfectly. I chose ckramer's solution as the accepted answer because it required no extra markup, but both solutions work great!

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected" id="item1" value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option id="item2" value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option id="item3" value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>

<div class="item1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a-item1" value="5" />
  <label class="checkbox" for="a-item1">Item 1</label> 
</div> 

<div class="item2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a-item2" value="6" />
  <label class="checkbox" for="a-item2">Item 2</label> 
</div>

<div class="item3">
  <input type="checkbox" id="a-item3" value="7" />
  <label class="checkbox" for="a-item3">Item 3</label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    dealWithSelect($("select").find("option:selected").attr("id"));

    $("select").change(function(){
        var selectedId = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
            var optionId = $(this).attr("id");
            // could probably also use $("."+optionId).show(); here
            $("div."+optionId).show(); 
        });
        dealWithSelect(selectedId);
    });
});

function dealWithSelect(selectedId) {
    $("."+selectedId).hide().find(":checkbox:checked").attr("checked","");
}
```

**Update to address questions in comments**

I've update the original code block, so it is all put together.  To address the initial state, we've got the `dealWithSelect` function. I opted for a slightly different approach to solve your second issue, which is to display all of the divs that have Ids that match select option values *before* hiding the appropriate div.  The list of items shown should be bound by the list of options in the select, so the other divs on the page should not be shown.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! Two questions. How can I get it to respect the select option that is selected by default? I am hiding other elements on the page with jQuery above this and they get shown whenever I switch select options. In fact, any div with "display:none" gets shown.

Comment: Thanks again ckramer. Regarding your second question, I tried both methods and they both end up hiding the divs permanently for some reason (they don't come back). Regarding the first question, I am a little confused on how to put those pieces together. Could you edit the original code you posted with these changes?

Comment: Awesome! This works great for the default option. For some reason the checkbox div's still aren't being shown again when you change the select box option. (eg. User has option 1 selected and it's corresponding div is properly hidden. Now user selects option 2 and it's corresponding div is properly hidden but option 1's corresponding div is not shown again.)

Comment: Sorry, check the latest update....I had a bum selector in there, since apparently I wasn't paying much attention to myself

Answer (score 1):

Edit: had it right the first time.

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val(); // 1, 2, 3, etc.     

    $("div:not(:visible)").show(); // show all
    // if you add a class to the checkbox divs (i.e. "selectdiv") replace with: "div.selectdiv"  

    $(".item" + selected) // get the div
        .hide()
        .find("input:checked") // find the checkbox inside the div
        .removeAttr("checked"); // uncheck the checkbox
});
```

To the Update:

```
$(function() {
    $(".item" + $("select").val()).hide()
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but the checkbox div's disappear permanently. I need them to come back if the user selects a different option.

Comment: See my Edit. You should provide a common class to hook the `show()` on instead of `:not(:visible)` as that will show all hidden divs on the page.

Comment: Thanks Joel! This works great. Any idea how to hide the default option's corresponding div? (see update above)

Comment: This worked perfectly, I chose the other solution as the accepted answer because it involved no extra markup, and I am not really sure if one way is faster/better than the other.